# My old project not working (Failed to load)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I'm trying to install (Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc - v5.0.0) and it failed as shown in the screenshots.

.Net v5.0.0 / .Net SDK 6.0.402

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I install the packages?

Comment: If you execute `dotnet --list-sdks` in command line, what is the output?

Comment: The error and some of your package references are for ASP.NET **Core** - yet `AspNet.Mvc` is an "old" package for the full/classic/Windows-only .NET framework. I believe you're mixing two sets of technologies here - you need to decide whether you have an "old" / legacy / full .NET Framework app (running with ASP.NET MVC 5) - or you have an **ASP.NET Core MVC** app on the new, cross-plattform .NET 5/.NET 6 framework - you cannot really mix and match for the most part .....

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your errors (and code if any) as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for text, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Comment: PM> dotnet --list-sdks
3.1.300 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
5.0.413 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
6.0.402 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

Answer (score 0):

Just as the error indicates,what you need is this [package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/metapackage-app?view=aspnetcore-5.0)(Microsoft.AspNetCore.App)

but what you installed was for asp.net mvc projects(Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc)

Asp.net and Asp.net core are not the same

If you want to migrate your old project to .net core ,you could follow this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/proper-to-2x/?view=aspnetcore-7.0)